# Upgrade ActiveMQ with existing configurations

Tags: activemq-classic

I am currently using ActiveMQ 5.16.4 where I have made the following configurations:

1. Activated the authentification for the webconsole (by adapting `config.xml`)
2. Activated SSL for the webconsole (by adapting `jetty.xml`)
3. Encrypted webconsole login credentials (by adapting `jetty-realm.properties`)

Now I want to upgrade to ActiveMQ 5.17.0, but I could not find any documentation how to do it without losing the configurations that already have been made in prior version to files like `config.xml`, `jetty.xml`, etc.

Can anyone help please and give some advice?

Comment: Have you tried using your existing configuration file(s) with 5.17.0? If so, what problems did you experience? I would expect the configuration to be (mostly) backwards compatible.

Comment: Ok I have downloaded 5.17.0. and used my existing config files and they worked. Thanks.